# What features does enabling ACPI 2.0 support in BIOS enable?

Tags: windows-7, bios, acpi

So I was booting up my box and for some odd reason my BIOS had lost settings (again), thus resetting everything to defaults. I was digging around making sure things were configured to my liking and noticed the option to enable ACPI 2.0 support. It was disabled by default but I was wondering: Do I need ACPI 2.0 support?

Motherboard is **ASUS M3A79-T Deluxe**.

**EDIT**: Updated to the newest BIOS version **1702** without any noticeable changes.

I should also note that I primarily use Windows-7 64-bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ACPI is required for power management to reduce electricity usage and wear-and-tear on the system components. Your motherboard supports the 2.0 revision of the ACPI standard which of course has some enhancements over the original spec, for supported hardware (that board is, but your other devices like CPU, monitor and hard-drive may or may not be—but probably are). The major changes were the addition of 64-bit addressing and device state and multiprocessor support.

So your options are to have power-management or not, and since you can always simply not use it (turn off the options in the *power* control panel applet), you may as well enable it in the BIOS.

The only reason to disable it is if it is a buggy implementation which ends up causing problems, but neither the motherboard’s [manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketAM2/M3A79-T_Deluxe/E4220_M3A79-T_Deluxe_V2_manual.zip) nor its [forums](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226072422/http://vip.asus.com/forum/topic.aspx?board_id=1&model=M3A79-T+Deluxe&SLanguage=en-us) mention any ACPI related issues. The [FAQs](http://support.asus.com/faq/faq.aspx?model=M3A79-T+Deluxe&SLanguage=en-us) for it do include [one question](https://web.archive.org/web/20130620173109/http://support.asus.com/faq/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=1&m=M4A79T%20Deluxe&s=24&hashedid=lhJiLTN5huPfCVkW&os=&no=5D263230-2B63-5952-9161-6F495239D170) about ACPI, but that is a specific [Vista related issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20100314124540/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930062) which is not even an actual problem, just a notice. Therefore, defaulting to disabled is just a curiosity which if really wanted, can be [asked](http://vip.asus.com/eservice/techserv.aspx?ptype=1&pmodel=M3A79-T%20Deluxe&SLanguage=en-us).

---

If you want to learn specifics about the ACPI spec, you can see the changes in Intel’s [Technical Update](https://web.archive.org/web/20070403170135if_/http://www.acpi.info:80/presentations/S01USMOBS169_OS%20new.ppt), or a short, [general overview](https://web.archive.org/web/20070610033047/http://www.acpi.info/presentations/ACPI_Overview.pdf) at the ACPI site. For real technical details, you can peruse the [full specifications](https://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_2.pdf).

ACPI is up to version 4.0 at the moment, but 1.0 performs most of the required functions for most purposes. The useful enhancements of later revisions are support for 64-bit, SATA, and PCI-E, but they also include a lot of stuff that most users probably don’t (currently) have or need like MPS, server, ambient-light sensors, user-detection devices, and USB3.

Answer (score 3):

According to [TechARP](https://web.archive.org/web/20120512002318/http://www.techarp.com/showfreebog.aspx?lang=0&bogno=381), this option does not enable specifically ACPI 2.0 features, but enables or disables ACPI itself!  Unless you want to go without all power management features (and even if not, it doesn't hurt to have them available), you probably want to leave that option on.

Comment: That seems mighty odd though, seeing as it was disabled by default?

Comment: Hmmm TechARP says: "If you switch from ACPI to non-ACPI mode, or vice versa, Microsoft Windows will fail to boot. You need to reinstall Microsoft Windows everytime you switch modes." - I just changed it and Windows booted fine. Maybe it's a pre-Win7 thing?

Comment: That's very possible.  I know that Windows 7 is a lot less fussy than XP in some other ways too, which is in turn less fussy than Windows 2000, which didn't even handle changing of IDE/SATA port very well.

Comment: As for being disabled by default, that is _extremely_ odd; it's possible that your particular motherboard's meaning for that option is different than what TechARP claims is the normal meaning.

Comment: @glenneroo, yes, it was an issue in Windows XP that changing the mode required changing the “Computer” device installed in Device Manager, which would rarely work without issue and usually required re-installation. @farfromhome, not really, the manual indicates that it is exactly what it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 absolutely requires ACPI 2.0 for power management.

It is quite puzzling that it was off and that turning it on didn't have a big impact. You should put your computer into sleep and check that it can wake up, which is a common ACPI problem on ASUS.

A possible explanation for the puzzle is that your BIOS does not fully support ACPI 2.0. The latest BIOS version for your model is number 1702, dating from 2010/10/22, and is available from [here](http://www.asus.com/Product.aspx?P_ID=ufZUFHN96LlrLL9J&content=specifications) (in the Download tab select "Windows 7").

If you decide to update the BIOS, please use great caution and ensure that you also have the media required to reinstall your current version. A botched BIOS update can brick the computer and will require intervention by a professional.

Comment: Updated BIOS to 1702 last week and didn't notice anything. Will try a sleep and report back!

Comment: See also [Use PowerCfg in Windows 7 to Evaluate Power Efficiency](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/).

Comment: Ok I can't sleep with or without ACPI 2.0. My box is a bit hacked: I have 2 PSUs running 10 HDDs. I was unable to find a way to connect the on/off switch to the 2nd PSU so I used a paperclip hack to have it always on. This means that when I sleep, the 1st PSU shuts off thanks to ACPI, but then I have to cut power to the 2nd PSU manually. Apparently this isn't "clean" and when I power up, sleep state is deleted. Hibernate (usually) works though!

Comment: So your motherboard is working as well as can be expected for a normal rig. A better hardware setup might also take care of the 2nd PSU, but I'm no technician.

Comment: Actually there is an adapter for the case (older CM Stacker) but I somehow lost it (or it wasn't included). I should find out what it's called and go find one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Everybody here seems to have just described what *ACPI version 2.0* is generically, without actually addressing what the "ACPI 2.0 Support" setting means within (at least) ASUS BIOSes.

Many people would be [ready](https://bit-tech.net/reviews/tech/cpus/overclocking-intel-s-core-i5-750/2/) to [swear](https://hardforum.com/threads/acpi-2-0-compliance-setting-on-asus-boards.1348497/) it relates to HPET (which [indeed](https://wiki.osdev.org/HPET), is an ACPI 2.0 structure), but on my P5LD2-X and P5QPL-AM the "High Precision Event Timer" device could still be seen in Windows regardless. After disassembling all ACPI tables (collected from the live system), this only seemed to very slightly change the FACP/FADT.

You get the extra [64bit pointers](https://wiki.osdev.org/FADT#Structure) (which doesn't sound important at all, but [apparently](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/285313/rtx-20802070-on-x58-legacy-system/2333410/) they do something?) and the [Preferred_PM_Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20071218055230if_/http://www.acpi.info/DOWNLOADS/ACPIspec-2-0c.pdf#page=128) field is set. And the [RSDT](https://wiki.osdev.org/RSDT) becomes an [XSDT](https://wiki.osdev.org/XSDT) (but checksum and addresses padding aside these are literally identical). **Nothing else.**

I believe this toggle exists in order to play nice with [old](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9864465/) or [buggy](https://lwn.net/Articles/600415/) OSs which wouldn't like ACPI 2.0 tables (and it's disabled by default because the only meaningful upside you would expect is just being able to better [determine](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/b/9/5b97017b-e28a-4bae-ba48-174cf47d23cd/CPA002_WH06.ppt) the system default power policy). Since AMIBIOS 8.00.12 (e.g. in [M2V-MX SE](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M2VMX_SE/)) you can instead choose between v1.0, v2.0 and v3.0.

EDIT: updated answer with info gathered from the jetway-AMI leak (which thankfully also included an older non-UEFI BSP, since Aptio doesn't seem to have this option anymore).
My assembly sucks then, so I couldn't make much sense out of the source code, but the latest setup screen help string says: *"Enable RSDP pointers to 64-bit Fixed System Description Tables. Different ACPI version has some addition."*